# Как определить, был ли редирект?

Tags: php, url, redirect, request

Есть метод, который производит редирект. Необходимо модифицировать или переписать его так, что бы перед редиректом он проверял, не было ли редиректа раньше, и, если был, реагировать на это.
Как можно реализовать проверку на наличие редиректа?

Это нужно, что бы избежать любых повторных редиректов и оперативно реагировать, если из-за чьей-то ошибки они появятся.

Гет параметры использовать нельзя, урл должен оставаться чистым.
Возможно что-то с $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], но пока не придумал, как это можно использовать.
Не могли бы вы мне помочь? Зараннее спасибо.

Comment: У вас не должно быть рекурсивных редиректов. Нечего городить велосипед с костылями. Лучше чините код

Comment: Проект с 2012 года, кода в нем горы, над ним работали десятки людей, еще десятки работать будут. Все места просто так не проверить. Способ выявления мне нужен ИМЕННО для того, что бы убедится, что рекурсивных редиректов нет и не будет, как я уже написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используются сессии - попробуйте при редиректе выставить контрольное значение в сессионном ханилище, типа хэш параметров запроса плюс таймстамп обращения. И при проверке "а был ли мальчик?" (в смысле редирект) смотрите разницу с таймстампом, а если возможны различные параметры в URL - проверьте заодно хэш этих параметров. По крайней мере, это позволит определить время последнего редиректа с этими параметрами в рамках сессии.

А в принципе есть стандартный механизм передачи данных "на один раз" до следующей обработки сессии вроде [session flash в Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#flash-data). Если есть возможность - воспользуйтесь одной из реализаций этого механизма, доступной для Вашего проекта, для передачи признака "повторного" редиректа.